Arranging Multiple Complex Figures in One Larger Figure Using Nested Plot Layout Matrices
I have a custom function that generates complicated arrangements of plots. Since the plot arrangements are complicated, using par(mfrow = c(...)) to arrange the plots will not work. I'm using the layout() function in my custom function.
Matrix_1 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5), byrow = T, ncol = 3)
Matrix_2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), byrow = T, ncol = 6)
fxn1 <- function (x) {
  layout(x)
  for (i in seq_along(unique(as.vector(x)))) {
    plot(0)
  }
}
fxn1(Matrix_1)
fxn1(Matrix_2)

I know this example is silly, but it serves as a good minimum reproducible example.
I want to take both of the figures created by my custom function - both fxn1(Matrix_1) and fxn1(Matrix_2) - and arrange them in a larger figure. Here are a couple things that I've tried that haven't worked.
# Attempt 1
tryCatch (dev.off(), error = function (e) {
  
})
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
fxn1(Matrix_1)
fxn1(Matrix_2)

# Attempt 2
tryCatch (dev.off(), error = function (e) {
  
})
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow = 1))
fxn1(Matrix_1)
fxn1(Matrix_2)

Is there a way to get both of these figures arranged side-by-side in a bigger figure? I'm essentially hoping to use a plot layout matrix inside another plot layout matrix (I want to handle more complex scenarios than require plot layout matrices to arrange). I've seen this post but I can't figure it out with my code. Because of the types of plots I'm making, I'm limited to using base R functions for them.
If it's possible to do it with base R functions, I'd love that, but I'm certainly open to using packages.
Thanks!
